# Is it possible to share a table between multiple lua_State in a single threaded application?

Tags: c++, lua, luajit

I have a table in one Lua script which I want to share with other Lua scripts, which are loaded in different lua_State, so they can call methods in that table. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unless you copy the data between states manually. Lua states are completely separate. Lua threads on the other hand share data. But do not confuse those with OS threads.